# Change hover effect with jquery colorpicker?

Tags: jquery, colors, hover, effect, picker

I can change the class picker-a background color with picker but i need change to the class picker-a's hover style? How can i do that with this codes?

Ps. Sorry my english.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ['feff35', 'fff600', 'ffe800', 'd0eb2c', 'aed14f', '40aa48'];
  $picker = $('.picker'), $stagepicker = $('.picker-a'),
    $.each(colors, function(i, color) {
      $picker.append('<div class="color-square" style="background:#' + color + ';"></div>');
    });
  $picker.on('click', '.color-square', function(event) {
    $stagepicker.css('background', $(this).css('backgroundColor'));
  });
});
```

```css
.color-square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28.75px;
  height: 28.75px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="picker"></div>

<div>

  <a href="#" class="picker-a">lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#" class="picker-a">lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#" class="picker-a">lorem ipsum</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event instead of click.

> Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse enters an element, or trigger that handler on an element.

And [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

> Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse leaves an element, or trigger that handler on an element.

*Code*

```
$picker.on('mouseenter', '.color-square', function(event) {
    //Set background color on enter
    $stagepicker.css('background', $(this).css('backgroundColor'));
}).on('mouseleave', '.color-square', function(event) {
    //Clear color on exit
    $stagepicker.css('background', 'none');
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ['feff35', 'fff600', 'ffe800', 'd0eb2c', 'aed14f', '40aa48'];
  var $picker = $('.picker');
  var $stagepicker = $('.picker-a');
  $.each(colors, function(i, color) {
    $picker.append('<div class="color-square" style="background:#' + color + ';"></div>');
  });
  $picker.on('mouseenter', '.color-square', function(event) {
    $stagepicker.css('background', $(this).css('backgroundColor'));
  }).on('mouseleave', '.color-square', function(event) {
    $stagepicker.css('background', 'none');
  });
});
```

```css
.color-square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28.75px;
  height: 28.75px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="picker"></div>

<div>

  <a href="#" class="picker-a">lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#" class="picker-a">lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#" class="picker-a">lorem ipsum</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

```
$picker.on('mouseover', '.color-square', function(event) {
    $stagepicker.css('background', $(this).css('backgroundColor'));
  }).on('mouseout', '.color-square', function(event){
     $stagepicker.css('background', 'transparent');
   });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ['feff35', 'fff600', 'ffe800', 'd0eb2c', 'aed14f', '40aa48'];
  $picker = $('.picker'), $stagepicker = $('.picker-a'),
    $.each(colors, function(i, color) {
      $picker.append('<div class="color-square" style="background:#' + color + ';"></div>');
    });
  $picker.on('mouseover', '.color-square', function(event) {
    $stagepicker.css('background', $(this).css('backgroundColor'));
  }).on('mouseout', '.color-square', function(event){
     $stagepicker.css('background', 'transparent');
   });
});
```

```css
.color-square {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28.75px;
  height: 28.75px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="picker"></div>

<div>

  <a href="#" class="picker-a">lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#" class="picker-a">lorem ipsum</a>
  <a href="#" class="picker-a">lorem ipsum</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on hover and remove on callback.

```
$stagepicker = $('.picker-a');

$stagepicker.hover( function(){ $(this).addClass("picker-a-hover"); }, 

                    function(){ $(this).removeClass("picker-a-hover"); });
```

And define the `hover` rules in class `picker-a-hover`

```
.picker-a-hover
{
... CSS RULES
}
```